# Do I really need 140 lbs of cement for a 5", 5' high vinyl fence post (31" in the ground)?

Tags: fence, post, hole, cement, vinyl

140 lbs Seems like a lot of cement, I was hoping to get by with just one 80# bag.

I guess the hole would be 12" per auger rental advice. I Live in Montana, not a lot of moisture but ground freeze down 8" at times.

Any advice appreciated. Also, they say to cement up to 2-3" below the surface, would placing dirt in first and tamping it down be a bad thing?

Comment: Buy two bags, if you don't need to use the second then you can return it. "*they say to cement up to 2-3" below the surface, would placing dirt in first and tamping it down be a bad thing?*"  **Can you clarify that ?** How is placing dirt in first related to concrete 2 inches below surface?

Comment: My thinking on that was the dirt placed in the bottom of the hole would raise the cement level, thus allowing me to use less cement. I am doing 18 posts! The first one using a hand post hole digger is telling me to rent a power auger!

Comment: Frost depth is much more than 8" in Montana.

Comment: thanks for that, not sure how relevant it is.

Answer (score 1):

A 12" hole seems overkill for a plastic fence post that can never really withstand a lot of force applied against it, at least not like a wood or steel post.

A well placed 9 or 10" hole will do very well in my opinion, and reduce the amount of concrete you need.

Keeping the concrete down a few inches will allow grass to grow around the post or you can set sod "plugs" aside for resetting after the concrete is finished. No need to wait for it to set up, for what it's worth, no need to add water to it until the dry mix is in the hole then water it.

I typically figure 2 bags per hole when I am doing posts. either 80 or 60 lb bags. Some take more, some take less.

Comment: Thanks for that! I thought a 12" auger was a bit much also. Getting some good advice on here and ideas. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Wow , I use an 8” auger for 4x4 posts and 1 bag , at the coast where a 4’ depth is required Because of high winds it takes 2 bags but for a 5’ fence unless it is a solid fence I would not be making such a huge hole or using more than 1 bag.